# Understanding C after getting used to scripting languages

Tags: c, learning, scripting

I use python and javascript in my daily workflow. I am really excited about understanding c as I am drawn towards contributing to projects that are written in the language but even after weeks of learning I am not able to wrap my head around how certain things work in C

Like, right now I am trying to figure out how to store structured data to a file in c so that I can experiment with building small tools and get a better grasp on the language. but so far I am just able to find the basic file read/write examples and coming from a scripting background I am used to using structured formats like JSON or XML.

Am I just asking the wrong question here or am I yet to find the right tutorial to follow?

> So far the guide that I found the easiest to understand was [this one](http://beej.us/guide/bgc/html/)
>
> Also searched through a [community post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) for resources but none I was most comfortable with the one mentioned above.

*I am really **really** new to C so any sort of help will be very useful*

Comment: Hi,
I downvoted your question, I believe it does not belong here but on Stack Overflow.

Comment: The most important thing to understand right now is that C is extremely bare-bones compared to Python/JS. The standard library provides only rudimentary functionality and there is no culture of sharing packages/libraries through a common repository. That you can't find easy examples of how to write data in JSON or XML format is **not** surprising and you better get used to that.

Comment: It's also too broad for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 6):

One of the biggest strengths of C is also one of its biggest weaknesses: it has a very small runtime and standard library. This is a strength because it makes C very portable and highly reusable as a base for other things, even in compilers of other languages. It's a weakness because you have to look to third party libraries for things that feel like they're "included" in other languages.

So search the internet for "json C library" and see what you find. If you're using Linux, the better, more widely-used third party libraries will be in your package manager, so search that as well. I have a `json-c` package installed, and I don't do C development anymore. It's there as a dependency of other software. Some linux distros have a separate `-devel` package if you want to compile code against a library.

You can also look in GitHub for open source projects you know that use json. See [gimp](https://github.com/GNOME/gimp/blob/72effc5a57f8fc389d94b7ae7676a923c761f6f6/configure.ac#L2279) for example. Sadly, though, a lot of C programmers choose to reinvent the wheel for things like this.

Comment: You can also learn about the file I/O mechanisms that are available in C, and design a file format that you can implement using those mechanisms.